# metadata_exists with 'page' throws error "Trying to access array offset on value with type bool"

Tags: php, wordpress

Why does this throw an error?

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
if ( metadata_exists( 'page', $post_id, 'my_meta_key' ) ) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Error:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/meta.php on line 692
```

Is 'page' not an allowed object type?

Thanks in advance …

Comment: From the looks of it it seems that `$post_id` is equal to `false` which would explain why you're seeing that error message. Are you trying to use [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) outside of [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)?

Comment: That was it. Needed to be `$object_id = get_queried_object();` with `metadata_exists( 'page', $object_id, 'cf7cl_checkbox_value' )`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @cabrerahector pointed out, the problem was that I was trying to retrieve the page ID outside of the loop.

This works:

```
$object_id = get_queried_object();
if ( metadata_exists( 'page', $object_id, 'my_meta_key' ) ) {
  // Do something.
}
```